# How to see classifications of ArcGIS Pro Iso Cluster Unsupervised Classification output raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, image-classification

I input a number of raster bands into the Iso Cluster Unsupervised Classification tool and asked for 5 classifications and specified a signature file to be created. The tool ran for a while and then completed. It put a raster in the Table of Contents that was a single solid color. I looked at the signature file and it had 5 classifications. I tried to look for a way to change the symbology of the output raster to see the classifications, but couldn't find it. How can I get a visualization of the classifications in the actual output raster?

Comment: Is it possible that the classification algorithm thinks that the entire area falls under a single classification? You might want to double check inputs, and/or try running a different set of images with the same inputs to see if this is the case.

Comment: Well, at first I thought it might think the entire area falls under a single classification. But when I opened the *.gsg file, I saw 5 classes listed.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for iso cluster unsupervised classification (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/iso-cluster-unsupervised-classification.htm) it looks like you define the number of classes as an input. Could the .gsg file get the number of classes from here, not the actual output? Also have you also checked the symbology of your raster? Is it truly one single value, or is it multiple values being colored the same.

Comment: Well I do think it tries to create the number of classifications I ask for, yes. I just figured the raster would reflect what's in the signature file. As far as the symbology, it says there one class with Value <= 1.

Comment: My understanding is that the signature file is for passing your classification on to new data. I would not assume that five categories there means five categories in your raster.

Comment: I think you're right. Also, some colleagues of mine said the raster I was using was too big and that I needed to clip it to a much smaller area. I'll be trying that next.